Earth is attacked and the female protagonist is conscripted to join the military. She travels to another planet to train
I read this book years ago but didn't get to finish it. The cover was animated like a comic drawing. It was about a woman on Earth and it gets attacked or something like that. The world united and formed a military (three letter acronym) that she had to join.
They go to another planet to train and live. She had to get used to the planet's atmosphere, pressure etc. Her first part in war was in the woods and she had to turn up.

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

I'm betting you can remember more. For example, what language did you read this book in? Was there explicit sex/violence/gore or was it aimed at a general audience? What was the woman's name? Who did Earth get attacked by? Was it set in the future? How did they get to this other planet? What damage did the alien attack cause? What was the name of the planet they trained on? Was there a love-interest?
